# I want the 3rd field to show the result of arithmetic of the first two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like the first two user inputed integer inputs of a rails app to populate a third field after some arithmetic is performed on them when a submit button is pressed.

I've used rails scaffolding.

Do I put my desired arithmetic function that I want to perform on my variables in my controller code below?

```
# POST /pls
  # POST /pls.json


def create
    @pl = Pl.new(pl_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @pl.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pl, notice: 'Pl was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pl }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @pl.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But for this portion,the answer is,

> Do I put my desired arithmetic function that I want to perform on my variables in my controller code below?

The best practice is to use model method to perform the arithmetic calculation. You can also use private controller method for this reason and call that method where you need. But its not a good practice to push the arithmetic code inside the  `create` action.

Answer (score 0):

That's something I'd actually put inside of your Pl model, in a `before_save` callback, so that if any of your two user inputed values changes, the value of the third is updated. It'd look something like this:

```
class Pl < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :update_third_value

    def update_third_value
      if first_value_changed? || second_value_changed?
        third_value = first_value / second_value # here is your desired arithmetic
      end
    end
end
```

Check out [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), which is available to all models by default, and [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), there's a list of all default callbacks available.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just to put my question in a better context. On a 'New' view in my app, there are three fields: income, costs, and profit. I want the third field to be calculated automatically when 'save' is pressed and then a new view is shown to the user with the profit displayed. Am I on the right track here?